# Decode the equation to quadratic equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Tring to create a equation of the form 
$$2^{x^2} : 2^x = 8:1$$ 
into the form of 
$$ax^2 + bx + c $$
or find the value of $x$.

The solution to this is $$x = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite $$a:b=c:d$$

as $$\frac ab=\frac cd$$

and use $\frac{a^x}{a^y} = a^{x-y}$ and $8=2^3$

Comment: So it would seem that the book got it wrong

Comment: @naveen.panwar Why do you think that?

Comment: did you see the question? In the I wrote the answer that was given in the book

Comment: @naveen.panwar Yes, but why do you think the answer is incorrect?

Comment: because it's not 3 and the answer is 3

Comment: @naveen.panwar The answer is not $3$. Why do you think the answer is $3$?

Comment: Oh excuse me I did not notice

Answer (score 1):

$2^{x^2} : 2^x = 8:1 \iff 2^{x^2-x}=8 \iff x^2-x=3$.